# Merge directories without overwriting conflicts

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, xcopy

I have 2 directories structures (A and B) that normally don't overlap.  I want to merge A into B.

The following command will merge the directories:

```
xcopy A B /E /Y
```

However, I want to be able to detect conflicts between my 2 directories, and don't overwrite if the file is already at destination (in B).  The xcopy will automatically overwrite files.  I don't want to be prompted for each conflict (/y).  I want to xcopy to return an error on conflict.

The /D option does not work either, because I don't care about the date.

I guess this is not possible with xcopy.  Are there other solutions for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the ROBOCOPY command to move all files that do not collide with existing files in destination. I've added the `/L` option that lists the outcome, without actually doing anything. If it works as desired, then simply remove the `/L` option to actually move the files.

```
robocopy sourcePath destinationPath /mov /xc /xn /xo /xx /L
```

The ROBOCOPY command produces a nice log of all actions that it takes. Using the above command, you can detect when files where not moved due to collision by looking at the `Files :...` line in the summary. If the number copied is less than the total, then there where collisions.

The ROBOCOPY command has *many* options that make it extremely powerful. Type `HELP ROBOCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY HELP` from a command prompt for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file e.g. dummy.txt fill ist with many lines containing `N` like this

```
N
N
N
N
N
```

Call `XCOPY A B /E /-Y <dummy.txt >output.txt`

any line in the outputfile containing a question was a conflicted file which was not overwritten.

Comment: Clever answer. I'm fond of automating stuff like this, **but** careful with locales: `N`[o] isn't applicable everywhere, so this should only be used when active language is known _a priori_. 

Answer (score 0):

This script merges 2 directories together using powershell. It only actions on the source folder, not the destination folder. It will move the file if it doesn't exist, delete it if the file hash matches. If the names are the same but the file hash is different then it skips the file.  This script was made 90% using ChatGPT.

```
param (
   [string]$srcDir,
   [string]$dstDir
)

$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
#Write-Verbose "Source $srcDir"
#Write-Verbose "Dest $dstDir"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -Recurse -File

foreach ($file in $files) {
   $srcFile = $file.FullName
   $dstFile = $srcFile -replace [regex]::Escape($srcDir), $dstDir
   Write-Verbose "Checking $srcFile"
   #Write-Verbose "DstDir after regex $dstDir"
   $dstDirNew = Split-Path $dstFile -Parent
   #Write-Verbose "DstDir after split path $dstDirNew"

   # Create the destination directory if it does not exist
   if (!(Test-Path $dstDirNew)) {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dstDirNew | Out-Null
   }

   # Check if the file exists in the destination directory
   if (Test-Path $dstFile) {
      # Calculate hash of the source file
      $srcHash = Get-FileHash -Path $srcFile

      # Calculate hash of the destination file
      $dstHash = Get-FileHash -Path $dstFile

      # Compare hashes
      if ($srcHash.Hash -eq $dstHash.Hash) {
         # Hashes are the same, delete the source file
         Write-Verbose "Deleting"
         Remove-Item -Path $srcFile -Force
      } else {
         Write-Verbose "Skipping (hashes do not match)"
      }
   } else {
      # File does not exist in the destination directory, move it
      Write-Verbose "Moving to: $dstDir"
      Move-Item -Path $srcFile -Destination $dstDirNew -Force
   }
}
```